# Flutter : Android/Web Error: Not found: 'dart:html' , 'dart:Js' and 'dart:ui' , packages: moor , url_launcher , firebase , google_map

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-dependencies, flutter-web, dart-html

I created a flutter project with firebase console , Also i added alot of tools and technologies in my project, I used firebase hosting and uploaded my flutter web app and it run completely fine

But when I tried flutter android , everything crush , There errors from packages that I used them.
My problem now from flutter sdk , yes you can't use dart:html and dart:js in your code if you used them in flutter android/ios , but flutter web is working completely.

I need to repair all the packages in the title , and this is impossible.
So guys I need help

ERROR Message : (part from message)

```
Invalid depfile: D:\Flutter_Projects\foody\.dart_tool\flutter_build\d14050bcfda46f13e2cbdc3fac4e2d51\kernel_snapshot.d
Invalid depfile: D:\Flutter_Projects\foody\.dart_tool\flutter_build\d14050bcfda46f13e2cbdc3fac4e2d51\kernel_snapshot.d
/D:/Flutter%20SDK%202/flutter/packages/flutter_web_plugins/lib/src/navigation/js_url_strategy.dart:9:8: Error: Not found: 'dart:html'
import 'dart:html' as html;
       ^
/D:/Flutter%20SDK%202/flutter/packages/flutter_web_plugins/lib/src/navigation/url_strategy.dart:6:8: Error: Not found: 'dart:html'
import 'dart:html' as html;
       ^
/D:/Flutter%20SDK%202/flutter/packages/flutter_web_plugins/lib/src/navigation/utils.dart:5:8: Error: Not found: 'dart:html'
import 'dart:html';
       ^
/D:/Flutter%20SDK%202/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/js-0.6.3/lib/js.dart:8:1: Error: Not found: 'dart:js'
export 'dart:js' show allowInterop, allowInteropCaptureThis;
^
/D:/Flutter%20SDK%202/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/moor-4.5.0/lib/moor_web.dart:9:8: Error: Not found: 'dart:html'
import 'dart:html';



D:/Flutter%20SDK%202/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/firebase_core_web-1.1.0/lib/src/interop/utils/utils.dart:44:26: Error: Method not found: 'getProperty'.
      map[key] = dartify(util.getProperty(jsObject, key), customDartify);
                         ^^^^^^^^^^^
/D:/Flutter%20SDK%202/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/firebase_core_web-1.1.0/lib/src/interop/utils/utils.dart:77:17: Error: Method not found: 'newObject'.
    var jsMap = util.newObject();
                ^^^^^^^^^
/D:/Flutter%20SDK%202/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/firebase_core_web-1.1.0/lib/src/interop/utils/utils.dart:79:7: Error: Method not found: 'setProperty'.
      util.setProperty(jsMap, key, jsify(value, customJsify));
      ^^^^^^^^^^^
/D:/Flutter%20SDK%202/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/firebase_core_web-1.1.0/lib/src/interop/utils/utils.dart:85:12: Error: Method not found: 'allowInterop'.
    return allowInterop(dartObject);
..............................
```

Packages :

```
 cupertino_icons: ^1.0.2
  #Response Design
  device_preview: any
  responsive_builder: any
  #State Management
  rxdart: any
  flutter_bloc: any
  hydrated_bloc: any
  equatable: any
  pimp_my_button: any
  #Animation
  page_transition: any
  velocity_x: any
  url_strategy: any
  lottie: any
  bouncing_widget: any
  #image
  gooey_carousel: any
  flutter_svg_provider: any
  flutter_svg: any
  parallax_animation: any
  octo_image: any
  cached_network_image: any
  parallax_image: ^0.3.1+1
  widget_circular_animator: any
  #text
  flutter_glow: any
  animated_text_kit: any
  auto_size_text_pk: any
  animated_flip_counter: any
  bordered_text: any
  #database
  hive: any
  hive_flutter: any
  #textfield
  intl_phone_field: any
  #progress indictor
  step_progress_indicator: any
  #others
  flutter_particle_bg: any
  webviewx: any
  webview_flutter: any
  liquid_progress_indicator: any
  universal_platform: any
  #universal scroll view (add it important after upgrade to flutter 2.5 sdk)
  connectivity_plus: any
  file_picker: any
  #this package support (android/ios/web) desktop is not supported
  image_picker: any
  camera_web: any
  image_cropping: ^0.0.5
  top_snackbar_flutter: any
  local_auth: any
  confetti: any
  file_saver: any
  crecexdiez_advertising: any
  translator: any
  speech_to_text: any
  text_to_speech: any
  camera: any
  http: any
  dio: any
  google_fonts: any
  font_awesome_flutter: any
  url_launcher: any
  intl: any
  flutter_datetime_picker: any
  signature: any
  permission_handler: any
  printing: any
  js: any
  flutter_multi_formatter: any
  dotted_border: any
  #support web only
  flutter_dropzone: ^2.0.0
  flutter_dropzone_platform_interface: ^2.0.0
  #firebase
  firebase_core: any
  firebase_core_web: any
  firebase_app_check: any
  firebase_auth: any
  firebase_auth_web: any
  google_sign_in: any
  flutter_facebook_auth: any
  firebase_auth_oauth: any
  github_sign_in: any
  cloud_firestore: any
  firebase_storage: any
  firebase_messaging: any
  #listview
  auto_animated: any
  #carousel slider
  carousel_slider: any
  #tabbar
  md2_tab_indicator: any
  bubble_tab_indicator: any
  #ratingBar
  flutter_rating_bar: any
  #rate_my_app
  in_app_review: any
  #day_night theme switcher
  day_night_switcher: any
  animated_theme_switcher: any
  #language switcher
  animated_toggle_switch: any
  #card
  flutter_slidable: any
  #number_picker
  flutter_elegant_number_button: any
  #moor (floor doesn notsupport web , moor has problem with hive in versions ,so do not change the versions)
  moor: ^4.4.0
  moor_flutter: ^4.0.0
  sqlite3_flutter_libs: ^0.5.0
  sqflite: ^2.0.0+4
  #path_provider isn not working on web (Mobile,Desktop only)
  path_provider: any
  path: any
  #sound effect (audioplayers doesn not support windows/linux , so we use flutter_audio_desktop)
  flutter_audio_desktop: any
  just_audio: any
  #dialog
  rating_dialog: any
  #share image (share_plus we can not share files (images) in widows or linux but can share text to email)
  share_plus: any
  #google apis
  flutter_polyline_points: any
  google_maps_flutter: any
  google_maps_flutter_web: any
  google_place: any
  google_geocoding: any
  geolocator: any
  #Captcha
  hb_check_code: any
  flutter_net_captcha: any
  g_captcha: any
  #fab (float action button)
  flutter_scrolling_fab_animated: any
  #payment
  flutter_braintree: any
  flutter_stripe: any
  #notifcation
  awesome_notifications: any
  desktop_notifications: any
  #mapbox
  mapbox_search: any
  mapbox_gl: any
  polyline: any
  #searchBar
  material_floating_search_bar: any
  implicitly_animated_reorderable_list: any
  #provider
  provider: any
  #syncfusion chart
  syncfusion_flutter_charts: any
  syncfusion_flutter_xlsio: any
  syncfusion_flutter_datagrid: any
  syncfusion_flutter_pdf: any
  syncfusion_flutter_maps: any
  #radar chart
  flutter_radar_chart: any
  #animation
  kenburns: any
  blobs: ^2.0.0
  #ai_barcode
  ai_barcode: ^3.0.1

dev_dependencies:
  flutter_test:
    sdk: flutter

  hive_generator: any
  build_runner: ^1.12.2
  moor_generator: ^4.4.0

  flutter_native_splash: ^1.2.1
```

This problem I know from dart compile (Android/ios use Dart VM , Web use dart2js)
this is why work fine with web but not on android
Do you have any idea how to solve it ??????

IMPORTANT: Don't say remove dart:html or dart:js , this is not a solution , this is like you are saying remove all dart:html or dart:js from all packages

Comment: Just remove dart:html or dart:js.

Comment: bro didn't see last two lines  , how can I remove dart:html from firebase packages ???? it is impossible @enzo

Comment: I was kidding. You can't use web dependencies in non-web projects in Flutter - or you remove them or you create another Android/iOS-specific Flutter project.